# domainuser to superuser

Tags: sudo, root, administrator

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and joined this to our company domain.
When i log in as a domain user with my domain passwd it works perfectly, also i can have sudo right so i can become a root user.
To achieve this i've added my domain name to the sudoers file at the bottom like %xxxx ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

But the thing is, when i want to add a printer thru the desktop GUI i will be prompted for the local administrators passwd.

Is there a way around this because in this way i will have to hand out our domain administrators passwd or i will need to create a passwd specific for this use?

Comment: Why not start the GUI with `sudo...`?

Comment: because some applications when started need access to domain servers and these will use root as username ones started with sudo. This is obviously not a domainuser with privileges on the needed servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes life is simple.... the solution was to add the domainuser via the terminal as a sudoer so open the terminal and perform:
*sudo adduser xxxx sudo*